# How to keep the background color's width when browser window becomes narrower

Tags: css, background-color

Here's the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {margin: 0; background: yellow;}

        .bar {width: 100%; background: pink;}

        .content {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="content">
            This is content~
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My intent is to have a pink bar fill the whole horizontal length of the browser display. The bar's content remains centered when said window is wider than 800 pixels, or remains fixed and horizontally scrollable when narrower. However, when the browser does get narrower, and if you scroll right, the pink bar doesn't reach the right end; in this case, the body's yellow is seen instead.

Seen this issue in latest Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should either make background of of content pink

```
.content {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;background: pink;}
```

or

make min-width of bar as content width.

```
.bar {width: 100%;min-width:800px;background: pink;}
```

Comment: The min-width solution seems to work nicely (even if against DRY), especially since it allows for the content part to have a different bg color.
Just noticed while inspecting elements during that "narrow browser, scrolled right" situation: the body element appears to not reach the rightmost border either. Apparently it needs the min-width thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to set `min-width` equal to the content width.

If you are trying to make the website for iphone & tablets as well, then you can define width for each view-port separately.